# При сборке гредлом пишет что использованы несовместимые с Gradle 6.0. фичи, но у меня Gradle 5.4.1

Tags: gradle

Я добавил плагин в гредле `nebula.deb`, теперь при попытке собрать что нибудь гредлом через `./gradlew` выдает `Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.`, но в тоже время если запустить без параметров то мне выдает что версия у меня меньше 6 `Welcome to Gradle 5.4.1.`. Что это? Как такое возможно, как это решить чтобы собиралось?

Answer (score 0):

Это было информативное сообщение, а не ошибка, на самом деле сборка работает